# How to check if value is NaN in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, how can we check if some value is `NaN`?

The following does not work:

```
someObject.someValue == NaN
someObject.someValue === NaN
```

Comment: I seconded this question because it is not (or is no longer) the same as asking about isNaN in Javascript, because Typescript disallows testing anything but a number now -- per the last comment below.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Same as JavaScript, [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN).

```
if (isNaN(someObject.someValue)) ...
```

Or the more modern [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN).

```
if (Number.isNaN(someObject.someValue)) ...
```

The difference between the two is that:

- `isNaN()` will coerce any non-number values (values with `typeof value !== 'number'`) into a number, and then perform the comparison; it's checking to anything that becomes `NaN` when attempted to convert to a number
- `Number.isNaN()` always returns `false` when it receives a non-number; it's actually checking for what is already `NaN`

In other words, with these values, you get these results:

| value | `isNaN()` | `Number.isNaN()` | `typeof value === 'number'` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `123` | `false` | `false` | `true` |
| `NaN` | `true` | `true` | `true` |
| `true`/`false` | `false` | `false` | `false` |
| `'a string'` | `true` | `false` | `false` |
| `new Date()` | `false` | `false` | `false` |
| `[]` | `false` | `false` | `false` |
| `{}` | `true` | `false` | `false` |

Comment: Anything that is not `NaN` returns `false`. Strings, `null`, `undefined`, booleans - they'll all return `false` from `Number.isNaN()` or plain `isNaN()`. The function does not test if something "isn't a number", but rather if it "is NaN" which is a specific invalid number value, in practice. To test if something is not a number, do `typeof something !== "number" || isNaN(something)`.

Comment: In case anyone else comes upon this, `window.isNaN()` will coerce a value into a number and THEN check if it is `NaN`. So `undefined` and `"hello"` will return `true`, while `undefined` and `""` return `false`.

This is why `Number.isNaN` was added, because this does check explicitly for `NaN` without the initial coercion.

Comment: Worth keeping in mind: `"123.123"` will return false, but `"123,123"` will return true.

Comment: @zeh As per Typescript (es5+) `isNaN()` only takes a `number` type as its first argument.

Comment: Hmm, this table is not 100% correct. When testing inside a browser `isNaN([])` returns `false`, which does make sense since `[]` is coerced into `0`. Or is this a recent change?

Comment: @Clarity You're right. I just checked the table and the description from references and it's coerced first. The idea that "non-numbers will always return `true`" is incorrect. I'm not sure if this is a recent change; it seems unlikely. I think it's more likely the original edit (done by a different author) was factually wrong. I've re-done all checks and updated the table and the description to be correct (the date and boolean values were also incorrect).

Comment: @zeh thanks for the update! I was working on a [similar table](https://claritydev.net/blog/what-is-the-type-of-nan#testing-for-nan-values-numberisnan-vs-isnan) but the results are not hardcoded and are the actual output of the statements using the value and it wasn't matching the results here, which got me wondering.